# workarounds to give "size" to an absolutely positioned element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, tabs, position, css-position

I have modified jquery mobile a little so a collapsible with *data-type="horizontal"* converts into a tab-viewer.

See my example page here - [tabview](http://www.stokkers.mobi/jqm/tabview/tab.html)

The one problem I have with it, is the need to position elements absolute/relative.

I need to absolutely postion the collapsible-content in relation to the relatively positioned *.ui-collapsible-set* to make the collapsible content section span across the full tabview width.

I would like to know if there are any workarounds to avoid positioning elements like this, because it creates all kind of problems in the regular flow of elements on a page.

Thanks for some input!

Comment: what's being positioned absolutely?

Comment: The `.ui-collabsible-content` elements are absolutely positioned so the content below them doesn't shift down when the content areas are opened. @frequent, could you setup a JSFiddle?

Comment: on the way. http://jsfiddle.net/tdpNd/

Comment: Try removing the absolute position on the _.ui-collapsible-content_. Then the tab just spans the tab's width and not the whole tabviewer width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way, which is awkward, but working...

Can be done with css like this:

```
.ui-collapsible-set-horizontal.ui-grid-a .ui-block-a .ui-collapsible-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 199.3%;
    padding: 0;
    }
.ui-collapsible-set-horizontal.ui-grid-a .ui-block-b .ui-collapsible-content {
    left: -100%;
    width: 199.3%;
    position: relative;
}
```

my problem was that I had to set pos:absolute on .ui-collapsible-content in order for the this element to cover the whole tabview.

The above works for a two grid tab, so basically I'm setting the width to twice the element width (a tabview-set, 2 tabs, each 100% width = set to 200%, 3 tabs, set to 300% etc) and using pos:relative to position the 2nd, 3rd, 4th tab to the left by all preceding tabs' width.

Works nicely and since I'm not using pos:absolute anymore, the content section now doesn't have to be set hardcoded (height 123px), but expands depending on the content contained.

Answer (score 0):

`.ui-collapsible-content` is a child of `.ui-collapsible`

If the headers are going to be floated to stack horizontally, but the content is to display full width below then you either need to:

A) take the content out of the flow (like you did)

B) refactor the html to get it out of there

```
<container>
    <headerArea><header></header><header></header></headerAread>
    <contentArea></contentAre>
</container>
```

Comment: I cannot modify the HTML structure, because it's set by jquery mobile to be like this. But good idea. Thx.